Why does the entropy not decrease when inserting a partition into a macroscopic amount of different particles?
Here is a thought experiment. Imagine a box with 10^20 different particles, all different types of molecules, such that they are not indistinguishable according to QM.
I insert a parition in the middle of the box. Of course since this process is reversible, the entropy is the same. But when I count the number of microstates, every microstate in the new system was also a microstate in the previous system, but the grand majority of the states in the previous system are no longer possible in the partitioned system, since each unique molecule can only be on one side of the partition. To me this seems like a paradox, can someone help me understand why my argument is incorrect?

You might be interested in reading about the Gibbs paradox.

Specifically, since the entropy is measured by the log of available microstates, a vast suppression in that number ends up as a much smaller reduction in entropy—a factor of two—which cancels out because there are now two systems. I'd like to read an answer that discusses this reduction in detail.

You can find many papers discussing this precise situation, for instance this one or this one.

FYI: I added a new answer to the suggested duplicate that you might find relevant.

@Wrzlprmft the second paper you linked was helpful, with the main point seeming to be 'if you define the particles to be distinguishible, there will never be an equilibrium in the box since each transition creates a different macrostate', though a lot of it went over my head

I meant to tag @YvanVelenik, apologies
